# Reading a Non txt file in C#

Tags: c#, file, jsp

I am trying to read the contents of a *.jsp file and need to retrieve a specific string.

I tried many file handling methods in C# but it seems all work only with txt files. Is it possible to use the same methods for a file with a different extension?

Comment: System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("yourfilenamehere.jsp"); or System.IO.File.ReadAllText("yourfilenamehere.jsp"); should work

Comment: When you say "it seems all work" - what happened when you *tried* to read the jsp file? It should work fine. When you're describing a problem, it's important that you say what happened. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Yes, the `System.IO` classes work just fine with files with any extension. Under Windows there's not an association between the file extension and the actual file contents. Perhaps post the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal IO classes in .NET *don't* depend on the file extension. You should be able to use:

```
string jsp = File.ReadAllText("page.jsp");
```

... assuming the JSP is encoded in UTF-8. You should find out the encoding of the file and load it using that encoding. I wouldn't be surprised if that turned out to be the problem you were having, although you haven't specified anything.

Comment: Thanks Jon. ReadAllText worked fine. I was opening the file first before trying that, which was causing the application to halt. Many Thanks for you suggestions. I'll put a code snippet next time onwards so it will be easier for everyone to understand the question.